# JSON Sorting by date

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, date

First of all i'm a complete newbie to this json, i have searched for solutions but seem i did not find the trick.

Where data looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [debtor_name] => Name 1
            [debtor_number] => 0001
            [statement_date] => 7/31/17
            [statement_period] => 07/01/2017 - 07/31/2017
            [due_date] => 8/31/17
            [statement_number] => 2017-07-0001
            [courier] => Handcarry
            [outstanding_bal] => 3,647.53
            [bal_br_fwd] => 3,647.16
            [age_cur] => 3,647.53
            [age_30] => 0
            [age_60] => 0
            [age_90] => 0
            [age_120] => 0
            [password] => 11291934
            [email] => rolex@bngtransmedia.com
            [counter] => 1
            [transList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 0
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000484236
                            [amt] => 7231.16
                            [desc] => MD-MONTHLY DUES
                            [debit] => 3584
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 1
                            [date] => 7/15/17
                            [dateNum] => 1500048000000
                            [ref] => 0000165008
                            [amt] => 3684
                            [desc] => CM-METROBANK
                            [debit] => 0
                            [credit] => 3647.16
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 2
                            [date] => 7/15/17
                            [dateNum] => 1500048000000
                            [ref] => 0000165008
                            [amt] => 3647.53
                            [desc] => 1% Discount
                            [debit] => 0
                            [credit] => 36.47
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 3
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000484237
                            [amt] => 7331.16
                            [desc] => MD-VALLEY SENIORS FEE
                            [debit] => 100
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [debtor_name] => Name 2
            [debtor_number] => 2665
            [statement_date] => 7/31/17
            [statement_period] => 07/01/2017 - 07/31/2017
            [due_date] => 8/31/17
            [statement_number] => 2017-07-2665
            [courier] => Sure Mail
            [outstanding_bal] => 18,194.93
            [bal_br_fwd] => 17,897.63
            [age_cur] => 5,193.00
            [age_30] => 6,196.01
            [age_60] => 4,984.71
            [age_90] => 1,821.21
            [age_120] => 0
            [password] => 05291962
            [email] => r.estemonio@gmail.com
            [counter] => 5372
            [transList] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 4
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000479082
                            [amt] => 18082.63
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 015904 JJ
                            [debit] => 185
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 5
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000485742
                            [amt] => 21666.63
                            [desc] => MD-MONTHLY DUES
                            [debit] => 3584
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 6
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000485743
                            [amt] => 21890.63
                            [desc] => MD-LOCKER RENTAL
                            [debit] => 224
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 7
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000481000
                            [amt] => 21920.63
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 026492 ANIX
                            [debit] => 30
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 8
                            [date] => 7/31/17
                            [dateNum] => 1501430400000
                            [ref] => PF00072305
                            [amt] => 18194.93
                            [desc] => PATRONAGE FEE
                            [debit] => 0
                            [credit] => 448
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 9
                            [date] => 7/6/17
                            [dateNum] => 1499270400000
                            [ref] => 0000481002
                            [amt] => 22010.63
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 027375 ANIX
                            [debit] => 15
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 10
                            [date] => 7/8/17
                            [dateNum] => 1499443200000
                            [ref] => 0000479083
                            [amt] => 22268.63
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 016332 JJ
                            [debit] => 258
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 11
                            [date] => 7/8/17
                            [dateNum] => 1499443200000
                            [ref] => 0000164358
                            [amt] => 17372.93
                            [desc] => CM-METROBANK
                            [debit] => 0
                            [credit] => 4895.7
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 12
                            [date] => 7/15/17
                            [dateNum] => 1500048000000
                            [ref] => 0000481003
                            [amt] => 17422.93
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 028985 ANIX
                            [debit] => 50
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 13
                            [date] => 7/15/17
                            [dateNum] => 1500048000000
                            [ref] => 0000479084
                            [amt] => 17735.93
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 016716 JJ
                            [debit] => 313
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 14
                            [date] => 7/22/17
                            [dateNum] => 1500652800000
                            [ref] => 0000478834
                            [amt] => 18289.93
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-08528DR
                            [debit] => 554
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 15
                            [date] => 7/29/17
                            [dateNum] => 1501257600000
                            [ref] => 0000479085
                            [amt] => 18642.93
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 017434 JJ
                            [debit] => 353
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [lineOrder] => 16
                            [date] => 7/1/17
                            [dateNum] => 1498838400000
                            [ref] => 0000481001
                            [amt] => 21995.63
                            [desc] => F&B CONCESSIONAIRE-F&B 026713 ANIX
                            [debit] => 75
                            [credit] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So i'm getting the data like this

```
$json = json_decode($_POST["list"], true);
```

I tried this line of code but seems not working:

```
function sort_by_date($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a['date']);
    $b = strtotime($b['date']);
   return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($json, 'sort_by_date');
```

I am trying to sort this JSON array by date in transList Array but i don't really know how i should call this variable on the array, any tips in the right direction are much appreciated!

Comment: `usort($json[0...n]['transList'], 'sort_by_date');`

Comment: what is this $json[0...n]?

Comment: You need to loop through all `$json` items and sort each item's `transList` array. `usort($json[0]['transList'], 'sort_by_date');` `usort($json[1]['transList'], 'sort_by_date');` `usort($json[2]['transList'], 'sort_by_date');` ...

Comment: Do `print_r($json[0]['transList']);` and update your question with the result.

Comment: Ok i try this usort($json[1]['transList'] and it seems do the trick how i am going to auto change this $json[0...n] through the loop?

Comment: `foreach($json as $item) { usort($item['transList'], 'sort_by_date'); }`

Comment: i tried this foreach($json as $item) { 
 usort($item['transList'], 'sort_by_date'); 
   echo '<pre>';
    print_r($json);
   echo '</pre>';
}  but why is it the data display 2 times?

Comment: Ok never mind my error i already correct it foreach($json as $item) { 
 usort($item['transList'], 'sort_by_date'); 
   echo '<pre>';
    print_r($item['transList']);
   echo '</pre>';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sorts the arrays in each transList:

```
foreach( $json as $k => $v )
{
    usort( $v['transList'], function( $a, $b ){
        $d1 = new DateTime( $a['date'] );
        $d2 = new DateTime( $b['date'] );
        if( $d1 == $d2 ){
            return 0;
        }
        return ($d1 < $d2) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    // For testing purposes, the array is print to screen to show sorting worked as required
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $v['transList'] );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

And just for testing purposes, I used the following data to mock your data:

```
$json = [
    [
        'transList' => [
            [
                'id'   => 'a',
                'date' => '7/15/17'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'b',
                'date' => '2/15/17'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'c',
                'date' => '7/15/16'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'd',
                'date' => '4/15/12'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'e',
                'date' => '3/15/16'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'transList' => [
            [
                'id'   => 'd',
                'date' => '7/15/17'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'b',
                'date' => '2/15/17'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'g',
                'date' => '7/15/16'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'a',
                'date' => '4/15/12'
            ],
            [
                'id'   => 'x',
                'date' => '3/15/16'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

To answer your question about further sorting by amount if date is equal:

```
foreach( $json as $k => $v )
{
    usort( $v['transList'], function( $a, $b ){
        $d1 = new DateTime( $a['date'] );
        $d2 = new DateTime( $b['date'] );
        if( $d1 == $d2 ){
            if( $a['amt'] == $b['amt'] ){
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a['amt'] < $b['amt']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return ($d1 < $d2) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    // For testing purposes, the array is print to screen to show sorting worked as required
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $v['transList'] );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: when the data has same date it interchange the position. Is it possible to add a condition sort by date and amt? or maybe date and id?

Comment: See revised answer, now has example of further sorting by amt if date is equal.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your help.